# AWS EC2 Elastic IP causing problems connecting to MySQL server with SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a MySQL server running on an AWS EC2 instance. I've created a user specifically for remote access from a specific IP. All access from this user requires SSL encryption (via the `require ssl` option during the `grant privileges` command).

The MySQL server has SSL enabled, I've created all the necessary server/client certs and keys, and I've put the client cert/key onto the whitelisted machine (another EC2 instance) and updated `/etc/my.cnf` with the locations of the cert/key.

Connecting from the command line e.g. `mysql -u user -p -h theserver.com` works fine.

Now, I'm trying to connect to the MySQL server from another machine (also an EC2 instance), which is a clone of the machine that I've been connecting from successfully. It's using the exact same client cert/key, with the same entries in `/etc/my.cnf`. I've whitelisted the new instances IP in the AWS inbound firewall rules for port 3306 on the server instance. I've added a new user for the new instances IP on the MySQL server with the same privileges and password as before.

But running `mysql -u user -p -h theserver.com` now produces this:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

I know this error is documented on the [MySQL SSL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html), but that can't be the issue because the 'old' instance can connect just fine using the same client cert/key.

There is one difference between the two instances that must be causing the problem. **The new instance is behind an elastic IP**.

Can anyone please suggest how I might fix this?

*Just to confirm, this is an SSL connection issue. I can connect successfully from the new instance if I drop the SSL connection requirement for the user.*

There's actually another difference between the new and old client instances. The new instance has:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.45, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

...whereas the old instance has:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

`openssl` is the same version (1.0.1) on both machines. ALthough the new instance is a clone of the old one (they're both running the Amazon Linux OS), I've updated the new instance OS to the `2015.03` release whereas the old one is running `2014.09`. So I guess the problem could potentially be some dependency that got an upgrade.

Comment: To what IP addres is `theserver.com` resolving on the client machine? The AWS private IP or the external elastic IP?

Comment: Running `dig server.com` from the 'new' instance is showing the elastic IP for the server instance. Sorry, I should have mentioned that the server is using an elastic IP too, but that shouldn't matter, should it, since the 'old' instance is connecting fine. Running `dig new.instance.com` from the server is showing the elastic IP for the client.

Comment: To be clear.  running `dig server.com` from both of the non-mysql machines has the same IP returned for the mysql machine?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just double checked it.

Comment: The elastic IP is likely to be a red herring. Error reporting in MySQL SSL is just about worthless, so that message could be anything.  What about `$ mysql -V` to compare the *client* versions on the two machines?  Are you using exactly the same cert, key, and ca-file on both systems?

Comment: I never even thought to check the versions, that was really stupid of me. They are very slightly different, question is updated.